Python minidump
I've got a python process running using PyInstaller. This process hosts a gRPC server, which for some reason stops responding after a couple of days. I am not allowed to analyze this on the machine on which it is running, and can not reproduce it in development machines.
Everything is running on Windows machines.
When using C++, I'd take a memory dump of a process (task manager, details, rmb on the process, create dump file). I'd then load this in Visual Studio together with the .pdb file, and be able to see exactly what code was running, what threads are running and therefore be able to figure out what might cause the hang.
How do I do this with Python? If I were to take a memory dump, how do I analyze it?
